# Python Object Iteration

Tags: python

Can someone provide an example of how to loop through this object in python and pull out 'value' where `api = 'interesting'` and `arguments.name = 'FileName'`?

Here is what I have so far.
This object has many more processes and calls....output has been omitted.

edit: I should mention that I am getting the following error when running this code:
"TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

```
for k, v in object['behavior']['processes']['calls'].items():
            if v['api'] == "interesting":
                           <loop through arguments next>
```

Object:

```
{"behavior": {
    "processes": [
        {
        "parent_id": "312", 
        "process_name": "test.exe", 
        "process_id": "1184", 
        "first_seen": "2013-03-02 17:22:48,359", 
        "calls": [
            {
            "category": "filesystem", 
            "status": "FAILURE", 
            "return": "0xc000003a", 
            "timestamp": "2013-03-02 17:22:48,519", 
            "thread_id": "364", 
            "repeated": 0, 
            "api": "interesting", 
            "arguments": [
                {
                "name": "FileHandle", 
                "value": "0x00000000"
                }, 
                {
                "name": "DesiredAccess", 
                "value": "0x80100080"
                }, 
                {
                "name": "FileName", 
                "value": "c:\\cgvi5r6i\\vgdgfd.72g"
                }, ...
```

Comment: What's wrong with carrying on with what you've started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've given as a starter in the question won't work because you are not iterating through the elements of the lists that are the values to the keys `"processes"` and `"calls"` respectively.  That is, you will need something more like

```
for proc in object ['processes']:
    for call in proc ['calls']:
        if call ['api'] == "interesting":
            fname = None
            for arg in call ['arguments']:
                if arg ['name'] == "FileName":
                    fname = arg ['value']
```

Then the file name you're looking for will be in `fname`.  This has no error checking, since I don't know where your data has come from.

Comment: Everyone who has provided input has been correct but in the end I wound up using this code. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing seems OK, 
but

1. Your indexes are off (look carefully there are lists
2. Your check seems to be invalid (`v` is a string, so `v['api']` is invalid).

So, try doing this instead, (I've taken your object as `i`)

```
for k, v in i['behavior']['processes'][0]['calls'][0].items():
    if k == 'api' and v == "interesting":
        print k,v
```

OR

```
for dct in i['behavior']['processes'][0]['calls']:
    if dct['api'] == "interesting":
        print 'api',dct['api']
```

OR

```
for dct in i['behavior']['processes'][0]['calls']:
    for k,v in dct.items():
        if k == 'api' and  v =="interesting":
            print 'api',dct['api']
```

OR if the there are multiple parts to each list,

```
for proc in i['behavior']['processes']:
    for call in proc['calls']:
        print 'api =>',call['api'] # a if here
        for args in call['arguments']:
            print '   argument.name =>',args['name'] # and another if here should do the trick.
```

**Why you get the error**
Try the following piece of code, and you'll understand what you were doing wrong

```
print type(i['behavior']['processes'])
print type(i['behavior']['processes'][0])
print type(i['behavior']['processes'][0]['calls'])
print type(i['behavior']['processes'][0]['calls'][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
object['behavior']['processes']['calls']
```

is a list, not dict.